# Reliance. netconnect on kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, 14.04, internet

I recently installed kubuntu. 14.04 and. I am not able to use Reliance. netconnect. on it. pls.help how to connect. to internet. using Reliance. netconnect. on kubuntu. 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Install wvdial package using `apt-get`

Open terminal, and type the following command

```
sudo apt-get install wvdial
```

2) Install `gnome-ppp` using `apt-get`

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-ppp
```

3) Open `gnome-ppp` from the terminal. Better to use `sudo` mode as you need to configure `wvdial`.

```
sudo gnome-ppp
```

4) You would see the gnome-ppp interface like below. You have to enter your reliance 10-digit mobile number in the Username & your password. Select #777 if you are a Reliance Netconnect Broadband+ user. put your 10 digit username `*********`, put your Password `********`" Then press the Setup button below.

5) Press your Detect button on setup OR select your device from select option for example  `/usb/ttyUSB0` and then close setup window and press connect. Now you will get a "connected" window prompt.     $#@&%

Answer (score 0):

Go to network connections. In that select mobile broadband tab.Follow the instructions and create one wireless network connection by selecting you connection as reliance in the drop down list. Once finished enter your reliance netconnect username and password which is usually the device number and try to connect. If not connected try to change some authentication settings like CHAP,PAP etc. It will work.No need to install the reliance netconnect+ setup in linux. It will work directly.